Episode where man discovers that each second has been "built from scratch"
It was a old tv show in black and white similar to twilight zone. This episode was about a man who become stuck in time in between the seconds. He discovers that every second of time has to be built from scratch. When we misplace something like our car keys it's because the builders forgot to build them but when we check again and they are there It's because the builders fixed it. We are not supposed to know about the builders so when the man is discovered they try to kill him. 

Welcome to the community. That's not a lot to go on. Answering the following questions will help us to respond. Any other plot details? What year did you see it? What was the language? Can you estimate the year and country of production? Was is live action? Can you describe the plot locale, descriptions of characters, etc. I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

Welcome, good question as well.

It must have been based on a Theodore Sturgeon story. I don't remember the name, but it was just like this.
